# Binding Dynamic URL to FB like Button in angular2

Tags: facebook, angular

I am trying to bind Dynamic URL to facebook page like button like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" [attr.data-href]="brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook" 
data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false">
</div>
```

But seems facebook gets default page link before data is coming actually as per documentation here

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#settings

as an alternate i hide this untill page is not loaded properly with *ngIf like this

```
<span *ngIf='brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook'>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-like" [attr.data-href]="brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook" 
    data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false">
    </div>
</span>
```

But in this button is not showing at all,

what to do ? any help or tip ?

Comment: button is not showing at all? What is the value of `brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook`? Also, minor typo, use double quote in `*ngIf`.

Comment: `brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook` is valid Facebook page URL, also whats the difference between `single` or `double` quoto ?

Comment: So you are very sure that `brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook` has value? e.g. showing it like this `{{ brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook }}` has value?

Comment: yeah i am damm sure that `brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook` has value, actually i know the problem too, my problem is facebook button binds the value before the data is coming in `brand_overview_detail?.brand?.facebook`

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. Tried FB.XFBML.parse(); tried loading the sdk after the value is set. Nothing works.

Comment: any idea? I was trying to inject the page with the iframe result, but as soon as I change it from a static `src` to dynamic `[src]` it stops working.

Comment: Exactly same case happened with me @Tomer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work, in a little hackie way:

I am adding the data-href with javascript not with [attr.data-href] and then I include the Facebook script:

in the template:

```
<div id="fb-like-btn" class="fb-like"  data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

In the component (I am using a setInterval to wait for the element to be on the DOM, but that is because of my implementation):

```
private _fbLikeIframeSrc(){
  let likeBtn = document.getElementById('fb-like-btn');
  if(likeBtn) {
    clearInterval(this._iframeInterval);
    let page = encodeURIComponent(this.promotion.callsToAction.page);

    likeBtn.setAttribute('data-href', this.promotion.callsToAction.page);
    this._initFbSdk();
  } else {
      this._iframeInterval = setInterval(()=> {
        this._fbLikeIframeSrc()
      }, 100
    );
  }
}

private _initFbSkd() {
  let d = document;
  let s = 'script';
  let id = 'facebook-jssdk';
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=************";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);


}
```

and behold, the like button appears!