# Angular2 dynamic Facebook Like, Twitter follow or youtube subscribe not working

Tags: angular, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk, youtube-javascript-api

I want to add simple social buttons to follow / like / subscribe on my angular2 page.

I am getting the page name from an API call, so the app is using a canActivate guard service first before initializing the template.

I am trying to do the simple thing as adding a script and a div like described in:

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript

Or Youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

but none of the above is working.

If I use a static value for Facebook page it is working, but not with dynamic value. ie:

```
<div class="fb-like"  data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

is working but

```
<div class="fb-like"  [attr.data-href]="dynamic page here" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

is not working.

The script initializes before the template is rendered, and I can't seem to get it to work with angular change detection. I tried also to go the API route, but with no success. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: I saw also this question that deals only with facebook, but no answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377461/binding-dynamic-url-to-fb-like-button-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic values should be made like

```
{{dynamicPage}}
```

So, you could add it to the $scope object in your controller's function like so:

```
<div class="fb-like"  data-href={{dynamicPage}} data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: That is not the right way to bind to data-href. you will get an error that data-href is not a known directive of the component. to bind data attributes you need to use [attr.data-whatever]="value" without the {{}}

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to angular 2... are you using TypeScript in this example? I'm looking at the docs at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html and I can see {{name}} as a dynamic example.